# Do desktop computers catch fire (often)?

Tags: environmental-health, consumer-products

My housemates don't want me setting up a home server because of fire hazard, I've seen very little, if anything, pointing to desktops causing fires, just laptop batteries ([Can overheating laptops cause fire?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/15792/24790)). I've got this system all set up with Proxmox and if that was in vain... (I accidentally started the OS setup with the installer flash drive on a USB 1.1 port so it took FOREVER)

I guess the question is... if I had a desktop on 24/7 unsupervised, would there be a non-negligible chance for it to catch on fire assuming stock CPU cooler, no overclock, PSU not near full capacity, dusting/compressed air regularly, and standard maintainence?

Comment: I looked around, and there seem to be a lot of people asking the same question ([e.g.](http://superuser.com/questions/89271/do-computer-system-units-actually-go-up-in-flames)), so it is notable.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/89271/do-computer-system-units-actually-go-up-in-flames) should be relevant here. I also leave my home desktop computer on almost 24-7 with no issues for the last 4 years.

Comment: ive actually had a fire start in the wall, because my computer used to much power and literally melted the wall socket down. luckly it was in an all cement basement so it just left some scorch marks. though to be fair the socket was anywhere between 15-80 years old, and i run a fairly powerful rig.

Comment: Anecdotal case here, but a coworker's custom built beast of a desktop started smoking and melted the plastic on its case when left running during a long weekend.

Comment: Almost all issues ive heard of stem to faulty or bad PSU's, when they burn out, sometimes they really burn.

Comment: Data centers, which have thousands of computer systems running 24/7, have automatic fire suppression systems installed for a reason.

Comment: But then, literally *any* eletric device plugged in constantly can pose some risk to fire. I think (for your roommate), the only meaningful question is: Does an unsupervised computer pose an unnecessary fire hazard. Most people would say no (assuming it's quality hardware, properly ventilated, etc). But some people (by my judgment, ridiculously paranoid--but that can only be an opinion), would say the risk is too high.

Comment: @Flimzy: But most offices have dozens to hundreds of standard PCs, many of which seem to be left running 24/7.  And of course, automatic fire suppression systems protect the valuable data center from fires from any cause, not just those started by the computer equipment.

Comment: @jamesqf: A fair observation, but in a data center, there aren't many other possible causes of a fire, since there's not much else in there :)

Comment: I think that unless your roomates are willing to forgo all electronic devices (TV, Microwave, stove, etc) because of the fire danger, they are being unreasonably paranoid that a computer is going to start a fire. There's probably a greater chance that a cell phone battery will cause a fire than a computer.

Comment: I'll add that I managed IT for a 500 person company  for 5 years - during that time we had zero fires caused by computers -- 75% desktops, 25% laptops, most kept on 24x7. We lost one server room power supply - smoke only, no visible fire or damage outside of the server, we had one small fire due to paper falling on an under-desk space heater (which was specifically against policy), several break room fires in the microwave and toaster oven, and one accidental fire suppression discharge when movers knocked off a sprinkler head).

Comment: There certainly are things you can do to minimize any risk.  Like periodically cleaning out the computer.  Home computers will often collect a lot of dust inside.  Make sure your computer has good quality surge suppressor.  Make sure that the circuit it is on is not overloaded, and has a proper fuse/circuit breaker.  Do not block the vents, and ensure proper airflow and cooling.  Do not place combustible materials on our around the system.

Comment: Just to play the Devil's advocate I think a lot of people are overlooking that a desktop/laptop *left on* 24/7 != a desktop/laptop *doing something* 24/7.  Additionally a server running 24/7 != a consumer desktop running a server OS 24/7.

Comment: Okay, this question has gotten me _exactly_ 42 rep as of now. Don't panic.

Comment: @Johnny Good point about all other electronic devices (TV, Microwave, stove, etc), but this should be limited to the ones that are supposed to stay turned on continuously like the OP's server. I guess that is the root of the concern as a running device is perceived (IMO rightfully) as having a greater whole order of magnitude of likelihood to catch fire compared to one which is turned off.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Do desktop computers catch fire often?**

http://www.nfpa.org/~/media/Files/Research/Fact%20sheets/office_fact_sheet.pdf

> In 2007-2011, there were an estimated 730 reported U.S. home structure fires involving office equipment per year...
>   [of these] Computers [accounted for] 48%
>   In 2007-2011, there were an estimated 630 reported U.S. non-confined non-home structure fires involving office equipment per year...
>   [of these] Computers [accounted for] 36%

So a little calculation: 48% of 730 + 36% of 630 = 350 + 227 = **577 computer fires per year.** *[Note that this category is a bit confusingly worded, I'm not sure what constitutes "office equipment" but I couldn't find computers in any other category, so they may all be accounted for in this one.]*

So computers seem to catch fire on average **about once every 15 hours in the US**. (2007-2011)

**Is the risk non-negligible?**
http://www.nfpa.org/~/media/Files/Research/NFPA%20reports/Occupancies/oshomes.pdf

> During the five-year period of 2007-2011, U.S. fire departments responded to an estimated average of **366,600 home structure fires per year**. ...
>
> *Leading Causes of Home Structure Fires: 2007-2011*
>   Cooking equipment 43%
>   Heating equipment 16%
>   Intentional 8%
>   Electrical Distribution and Lighting equipment 6%

A little more math:
43% of 366,600 = 157,638 US home fires caused by cooking equipment
48% of 730 = 350 US home fires caused by computers (see above)
350/157,638 = 1 : 450
**You are 450 times as likely to have a (reported) US home fire from cooking equipment than a computer.**

Maybe you could just eat out one more day per year instead of cooking, this should satisfy your safety conscious room-mates by mitigating the added risk of an extra computer.

Comment: The statistics you referenced: are they for desktop computers, or are they for all computers (including laptops, and/or including rechargers)?

Comment: @ChrisW It's hard to tell.  Explicitly not telephones, answering machines, "computer related", or "other office".  I'll see if I can track down a better explanation.

Comment: @ChrisW I dead ended on that particularly, need to pay for more info.  But I found an older report (1999-2003) that had similar metrics for a more explicit "computers", "computer monitors", "computer printers", "unclassified computers" and "mobile computers" were mentioned.  So I think the above probably refers to all computers. http://www.nfpa.org/~/media/Files/Research/NFPA%20reports/Appliances%20and%20equipment/OSComputer.pdf

Comment: "All computers" is OK: it means that the number you referenced is an upper bound, i.e. that the number or desktop computers is equal-to-or-less-than (i.e. no greater than) the number you referenced.

Comment: @ChrisW and servers, and desktops running server software, and old dusty laptops running server software in closets with newspapers on top and a tank of gasoline in the corner.

Comment: I would think that laser printers may form a large part of that percentage, with paper dust buildup, higher temperatures, friction, etc..

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I don't think that printers are included in the metric.

Comment: to put it in another perspective, 577 computer related fires a year in the US, which is probably roughly one in a million computers implicated as being a possible source of a fire. Not exactly a high risk. And that includes old and poorly maintained computers, computers being tinkered with inexpertly, computers shorting out due to lightning strike, etc. etc.